# Add white-noise on image based on SNR

Tags: python, signal-processing, whitenoise

I would like to add white noise to an original image with different SNR levels, but not sure how to do.

The original image is `(256, 128)` I am using `acoustics` package to add noise.

```
original = cv2.imread(path)
white = acoustics.generator.white(256*128).reshape(256, 128)
out = original + white*255

cv2.imwrite(path, out)
```

My questions:

1. Does `log10(mean(original)/ std(original + white*255))` count as SNR?(according to [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal-to-noise_ratio_(imaging)))
2. If so, can I just modify `*255` this number to modify SNR?
3. If not, how can I calculate the SNR value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key fact is that (this is maths, not code)

```
SNR = mean(s) / std(n)
```

Multiplying the noise by some constant `A` results in a new SNR -- `SNR_new`

```
mean(s) / std(A*n) 
= mean(s) / (A * std(n)) 
= (1 / A) * (mean(s) / std(n)) 
= SNR / A
= SNR_new
```

So working backwards, I *think* this is the correct approach in python is:

```
def add_noise(signal, snr):
    ''' 
    signal: np.ndarray
    snr: float

    returns -> np.ndarray
    '''

    # Generate the noise as you did
    noise = acoustics.generator.white(signal.size).reshape(*signal.shape)
    # For the record I think np.random.random does exactly the same thing

    # work out the current SNR
    current_snr = np.mean(signal) / np.std(noise)

    # scale the noise by the snr ratios (smaller noise <=> larger snr)
    noise *= (current_snr / snr)

    # return the new signal with noise
    return signal + noise
```

Comment: Thank you! I am trying out this solution now. The reason I use `acoustics.generator` is because I have to generate various kinds of noise, and seems this package will be more convenient.

Comment: A small question about `SNR = mean(s) / std(n)`. I think it's `log10(mean(s)/ std (n))`  since SNR use dB for unit?

Comment: I've figured it out that SNR doesn't have to be in dB. Thanks again!

Comment: @sealpuppy yes exactly, to convert from dB to just a number use `snr = 10.0 ** (snr_db / 10.0)`